# Remove mirrored effect from front camera

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently using the [camera plug-in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera#-readme-tab-) on flutter. Is there a way to remove the mirror effect from the front camera (selfie camera) when you take a picture?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the transform widget to manually mirror the camera widget:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math; // import this

Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
  child: /*Your Camera Widget*/,
)
```

Comment: Please try yourself before suggesting answer, this will only rotate frame not remove the mirror effect within frame.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I let the camera widget normal and I apply the transform in preview.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

if (bytesImage != null) ...[
  SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    child: Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
      child: Image.memory(
        bytesImage!,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
],
```